# Web To Lead is not creating Leads in Salesforce

Tags: web2lead

I am using salesforce sandbox. When I tried to create Lead using Web To Lead I end up with no result.

when I submit the form I am getting following text,

Your request has been queued.

Record Information:

city: xxx
company: xxx
debug: 1
debugEmail: xxx@xxx.com
email: xxx@xxx.com
encoding: UTF-8
first_name: TestLead
last_name: TestLead
lead_source: web
oid: 00DO00xxxxxx
retURL: https://www.google.com/
state: state
submit: Submit Query

After getting the above information, I went to check the Lead panel, the lead is not created.

Note: My salesforce has custom domain name its not test.salesforce.com
Please let me know if that is the problem.
URL is, https://xxx.cs5.my.salesforce

```
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

    <form action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="oid" value="00DXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="https://www.google.com/">

    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
    <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
    <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
        <input type="hidden" name="debug" value="1">          -                 
        <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="test@test.com">                       
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    <label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    <label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    <label for="city">City</label><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    <label for="state">State/Province</label><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" /><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You can try to debug by uncommenting 
`<input type="hidden" name="debug" value="1">                
<input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="test@test.com"> ` and putting your email address

Comment: It's been done. I got "Your request has been queued." But no leads created. Thanks

Comment: Are you also sure the org Id is the one from your sandbox, and not your production org Id?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure. I have double checked it and I am having the sandbox ORG ID only not production org ID.

Comment: Don't you also need to set a **Lead Status**? It's one of those required fields you can't get rid off, right?

Comment: Have you checked your validation rules?

Comment: I've tried adding that too.
<input type="hidden" name="lead_source" value="継続フォロー"/>

Below is the picklist values of lead status field in salesforce
継続フォロー ,
来場見込み  ,

Comment: @SFIntegrator : No. May I how to do it?

Comment: Go to : Setup--> Customize --> Leads --> Validation Rules.  Check if any rule is failing.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt While generating the Web-to-Lead Form, I couldn't find "Lead Status" field in the available fields. I have "Lead Source" but not "Lead status". You have any idea?

Comment: Seems I was wrong, you can't set the field through Web-to-Lead. Have you checked @SFIntegrator suggestion? Might be one of your validation rules blocks off the creation of the Lead.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you much. May I know how set validation rule? I have absolute no idea.

Comment: Go to Setup--> Customize --> Leads --> Validation Rules, check if there are any active validation rules. If you can't get your head around them, post them here.

Answer (score 0):

Check duplicate rule from setup and lead validation rule, you can temporarily disable both and test, you should get your lead.

Also, you should set an account you have access to Default Lead Creator, this way, if a lead is not created, you will get the error as to why, which will help you identify and fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).